# How to initialise a pointer to a pointer when the final address isn't known?

Tags: c++, pointers

In this example, I'd like to pass a pointer pointer to the future, not-yet-allocated `someObject` to a function. (Please don't ask why.)

```
int main(void) {
    functionThatNeedsSomeObject();

    SomeClass someObject(0);
}
```

I'm trying to do that using a pointer to a pointer. This is my attempt:

```
int main(void) {
    SomeClass** ppSomeObject;
    functionThatNeedsSomeObject( ppSomeObject);

    SomeClass someObject(0);
    *ppSomeObject = &someObject;
}
```

But in my code, `ppSomeObject` is uninitialized when it is passed. Of course the second-layer pointer can't point to the object, but how can I make the first-layer pointer point somewhere that I can change later, when `someObject` is created?

Should I do something like this? Even if it works, creating an intermediate pointer feels unnecessary.

```
SomeClass* pSomeObject = 0;
SomeClass** ppSomeObject = &pSomeObject
```

Comment: `SomeClass someObject();` does not define an object of type `SomeClass`. It declares a dunction that takes nothing and returns `SomeClass`

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Sorry, I didn't include the argument.

Comment: I'm still going to ask why you're doing this, since there are a few ways to do this and also some good ways to avoid it. What you need depends on the use case.

Comment: I don't get your pproblem

Comment: @larsmans I'm developing for a microprocessor with a large legacy codebase. `someObject` is the only way of dumping more than a byte of debug data. The function that needs `someObject` registers another object that will be used periodically, and from which I need debug output.

Comment: @Zaibis What is unclear in the question except for the reason that I need it solved?

Comment: Why is `SomeClass* pp = NULL; functionThatNeedsSomeObject(&pp);` not a viable solution?

Comment: @Andreas why your solving try doesn't work?

Comment: @MadScienceDreams That, like all the current answers, ends up with a pointer in the main scope. I don't want to change the line `SomeClass someObject(0);`

Comment: @us2012 probably something like a vector function which jsut needs to store so occurence of the object and jsut alter want to work with it.

Comment: @us2012 It creates an observer that registers itself with an observable singleton and is notified later.

Comment: After pondering this, I find that all of these requirements and all possible solutions are just poor programming practice. Something is fundamentally flawed in the program design, you should focus on that instead of creating some makeshift solution that spreads the poor practice further all over your program...

Comment: @Lundin I was given a large codebase and am paid to add a feature to it, not to refactor it. This double pointer isn't something that will remain in the program, but just be used temporarily for debug output.

Comment: @larsmans What about the two answers? Don't they work?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the pointer by reference:

```
void functionThatNeedsSomeObject(SomeObject*& rpObject)
{
    // do stuff
}

int main()
{
    SomeObject* pSomeObject = NULL;
    functionThatNeedsSomeObject(pSomeObject);
    SomeObject someObject(0);
    pSomeObject = &someObject;
    // NOTE:  when the function ends, someObject is destroyed, so the pointer is dangling
}
```

Comment: Note that the lifetime of the pointer passed into `functionThatNeedsSomeObject` is, in this case, limited the the scope where `pSomeObject` was created.

Comment: The object should be created with `SomeClass someObject(0)`. I don't want to change that part of the code. But I suppose that I could just do `SomeClass someObject(0); pSomeObject = &someObject;` and still pass a reference to the pointer?

Comment: @Andreas:  Yes, you can do that as well.  I'll modify the solution to show that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a reference or a pointer to a pointer and change it later on, the passed thing has to have a memory location.

You could do something like`SomeClass** ppSomeObject = new SomeClass*;` and delete the pointer later on (in the end).
That being said, there's often a better way to do things and make proper use of RAII

Comment: @Andreas I don't see why. All it says is "give me enough memory for a pointer and let ppSomeObject point to that place in memory".

The type will only be used for type safety and pointer arythmetic of *ppSomeObject. No instance of SomeClass is created by the new statement